# Return all values if parameter is NULL using SQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

I am not sure what is the right way to do this.

I basically want to return all values if value for certain filter is not defined.

Get request is made with filters like this:

`url.com?filter1=abc&filter2=123&filter4=33`

so as `filter3`was not defined i want to return all values regardless what their filter3 value is. Easy logic right.

But if I try to implement in SQL, I get stuck.

`SELECT * from TABLE_NAME
WHERE filter1 = $1
AND filter2 = $2
AND filter3 = $3
AND filter4 = $4`

.

How can I modify SQL above to respond to undefined/blank value and return all. Or is this even correct strategy.

Comment: If you're handling the request why not just use a different SQL command? Or build the command based on the parameters you have? What are you using on the back end?

Comment: What you are suggesting could be the better way, can you \show an example. This is that something came up to mind so I am doing it. Other was use if else for every condition which doesn't scale at all. Five parameters would mean 5 if else statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you have indexes, it is better to build the custom SQL.  But, if performance is less of an issue (say the table is small), just do the explicit comparison:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ($1 IS NULL or filter1 = $1) AND
      ($2 IS NULL or filter2 = $2) AND
      ($3 IS NULL or filter3 = $3) AND
      ($4 IS NULL or filter4 = $4);
```

If the value is passed in as something other than `NULL`, then adjust the logic accordingly.  For instance:

```
WHERE ($1 = '' or filter1 = $1) AND
      ($2 = '' or filter2 = $2) AND
      ($3 = '' or filter3 = $3) AND
      ($4 = '' or filter4 = $4);
```

Comment: usually i think it's blank, what would i put for blank string or number. In nodejs, this is the code : `db.query( "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE C_1 = $1 AND C_2 = $2", ['test', undefined]")`... not sure what `undefined` becomes